# Image align options in image dialog of CKeditor4

Tags: javascript, image, ckeditor, fckeditor

I deployed new CKeditor4 (instead of FCKeditor) and noticed lack of align image options in dialog.
FCKeditor has a lot of align options, but CK - only 2: left and right.

[Screenshot](http://st.datapic.ru/img/14-02/22/FH2DcbPfrIuUWdjKFQC4xpH2S.png)

Does anybody know some trick to fix this? Maybe any plugin of magic-setting :)
Helps men!

Comment: I'v found how to add values to select, but they doesn't work.
File is <ck_path>/plugins/image/dialogs/image.js.
I'v found the first occurence of substring "cmbAlign" and replace code below found block
`[c.lang.common.notSet, ""],
 [c.lang.common.alignLeft, "left"],
 [c.lang.common.alignRight, "right"]`

with


`['', ""],
 ['По левому краю', "left"],
 ['Абс понизу', "absbottom"],
 ['Абс посередине', "absmiddle"],
 ['По базовой линии', "baseline"],
 ['Понизу', "bottom"],
 ['Посередине', "middle"],
 ['По правому краю', "right"],
 ['Текст наверху', "texttop"],
 ['Текст внизу', "top"]`

Comment: I'v found the reason why above code is not apply formatting. FCKeditor uses deprecated align property to align images, but CKeditor uses float property (its valid values are left and right).